# What are the reasons to have an API back end if everything required can be handled securely by direct Database connection?

Tags: performance, database-design

Today's database allow strict user restrictions, such as readonly on specific tables.

If a client application is very simple and only needs to read a database, is it a better idea to allow the client to directly connect to the databse without an API back end?

What are the reasons to have an API back end if everything required can be handled by the Database?

The current norm is to make the database local access and only expose the back end.

I presume this will make things faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only thinking about the cases of non-nefarious users. While yes one can lock down a database to make it read only so that the end users don't accidentally change the data, leaving an internal database server accessible from the outside world leaves it open to a higher risk of vulnerabilities.

There's a multitude of attack vectors, some even undiscovered still, when exposing a whole server to the internet. An API is already a much more controlled technological implementation that eliminates most of those attack vectors and helps minimize vulnerabilities.

Additionally, an API helps centralize communication to your database servers from your applications. Should you need to migrate your database server to a different host name for example, instead of having to update your database connections in each of your applications, you'd only have to update it in one place - the API. (Of course there's many other ways to manage such a change as well, such as at the network level, but just another benefit worth mentioning.)

Finally, another thing worth mentioning is having an API helps improve testability by being able to decouple all tests (relevant to database calls) from the specific applications consuming the calls. Rather, you can refactor them into a single dedicated test project that consumes the calls as well.

Comment: Also to note I think API is better to prevent DOS attacks